# Who was Adina? (Lavan's wife)

Tags: history, historical-figures, agada-stories-legends, lavan

In [Sefer Hayashar](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaYashar_(midrash),_Book_of_Genesis,_Toldot.6) it says:

> ויזרע יצחק בארץ ההיא, וימצא בשנה ההיא מאה שערים ויברכו ה׳. ויגדל האיש ויהי לו ובשנת חמישים ושש שנים לחיי יעקב, באו אנשים מחרן ויגידו לרבקה על אודות לבן בן בתואל אחיה. כי אשת לבן היתה עקרה בימים ההם ולא ילדה, וגם כל אמהותיו לא ילדו לו. ויזכור ה׳ את עדינה אשת לבן אחרי כן, ותהר ותלד שתי בנות תאומות. ויקרא לבן את שמות בנותיו, את שם הבכירה לאה ושם הקטנה רחל. ויבואו האנשים ההם ויגידו לרבקה את הדברים האלה, ותשמח רבקה מאוד כי פקד ה׳ את אחיה ויהיו לו בנים.
> And in the fifty-sixth year of Jacob’s life some ‎people arrived from Haran, bringing Rebekah tidings concerning her brother Laban, the son of ‎Bethuel. For Laban's wife had been barren in those days without any off spring, nor did the ‎maid-servants of Laban bare children unto him. And after some time the Lord remembered ‎Adinah, Laban's wife, and she conceived and bare two daughters, twins, and Laban named his ‎daughters, calling the name of the oldest one Leah, and the name of the youngest one Rachel. ‎And when those people arrived and told Rebekah these things, Rebekah rejoiced greatly that ‎the Lord had remembered her brother and that he had been blessed with children.

Is there any more information on who Adina was?

I.e. Who her parents were? Or other pertinent information.

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/theJewishWoman/article_cdo/aid/4675456/jewish/Who-Is-Adina.htm

Comment: The similar name Edna appears in the apocryphal [Testament of Naphtali](https://www.sefaria.org.il/The_Testaments_of_the_Twelve_Patriarchs%2C_The_Testament_of_Naphtali_the_Eighth_Son_of_Jacob_and_Bilhah.2.1?vhe=Tsavaat_HaShevatim_--_Wikisource&lang=bi) as the name of a slave of Lavan who was given by him to a man named Rotheus and their daughters were Zilpah and Bilhah. By the way, the Testament of Naphtali, without the opening regarding his maternal grandparents, was found in two medieval Jewish texts.

Comment: @Harel13 interesting. Which texts?